# Devcomponent AdvTree: Nodes aligns to bottom of the tree if node text reaches the horizontal border

Tags: vb.net, treeview, dotnetbar

I have created a file management system using the DotNetBar AdvTree. Everything is working fine until I came across this bug which aligns all the nodes of a treeview to the bottom on expand. This only happens when the length of the node text reaches the horizontal border of the tree.

Please see the screenshot below for a better understanding of what I mean.

[AdvTreeScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXJOj.png)

I have already tried changing the text of the node so that if it's greater than the accepted length, trim the extra characters from the string. Although it fixed the issue to do with keeping the nodes fixated and avoid it aligning to the bottom, I however have other functions which makes use of the ".FullPath" method call to generate a directory path. Does anyone know a way to go around this problem? I want the nodes to stay at their respective positions and expand the nodes without it aligning all the way to the bottom of the tree. I have been trying to find documentation on dotnetbar AdvTree, but there were nothing or at least not enough information. Every search leads me to "rearrange" or "sort" articles. I am at a loss at the moment.

It would be great if someone could point me to the right direction. Any kind of advice to resolve this problem would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been able to find a proper solution to my problem but I have found a way to go around it by adding a column to my AdvTree. This eliminates the bug in my system, however if anyone knows a better way to fix the problem please let me know.